# What is this bumpeq-like symbol called?

Tags: geometry, notation

I have been searching all over the internet for this one symbol, it looks just like the symbol for equipollence, the so-called bumpeq:

[image: image from Wikipedia]

but what is it called the "underline" is missing so its just the line with the arc in the middle?

It seems the astrology sign for Libra is the same as the "bumpeq"

Comment: Like omega $\Omega$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes kind of like omega but the lines are much longer and the arc doesn't bulge out that much it's just a line with a arc in the middle, and where the arc begins the line ends then continues after the arc ends. Actually i think it might have been omega i was looking for.

Comment: Is this a question about the name of the symbol (and if so, have you ever actually come across it anywhere), or is it about how to produce the symbol in $\LaTeX$?

Comment: I don't think there's a symbol like the one you describe. $\bumpeq$ is just an equality sign with a bump on the upper line. There's no "bump" sign alone - not a $\LaTeX$ symbol I'm aware of, at least.

Comment: Anyway, for any such inconvenience, you might want to try this: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Unless you can provide some context for this, it is unlikely we can answer.